# ld: library not found for -lsocket

Tags: ios, cmake, cross-compiling

When cross-compiling (including Curl, among others) for iOS using [this toolchain](https://github.com/leetal/ios-cmake), I get the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -lsocket
```

Though `-socket` is not a thing on iOS. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/21971) and [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/18121), this is solved by setting the following CMake option:

```
-DENABLE_STRICT_TRY_COMPILE=ON
```

More details are given in those links:

> CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS relies on actually linking a binary to see if the linker is happy with the requested symbol and library name.  The ios.toolchain.cmake file does set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY), which causes try_compile to not link a real executable.  Instead it just creates a .a static library archive, which doesn't actually resolve any symbols.  That makes CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS accept any symbol.